# trouble when build with boost filesytem

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use boost filesystem functions and I searched my build log and find these lines:

> 1>    Searching C:\local\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-1_55.lib:
>   1>    Searching C:\local\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_55.lib:
>   1>    Searching C:\local\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\boost_system-vc90-1_55.lib:

so it did find the libs.

what I med are:

> proc1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned __int64 __cdecl boost::filesystem::detail::file_size(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::system::error_code *)" (?file_size@detail@filesystem@boost@@YA_KAEBVpath@23@PEAVerror_code@system@3@@Z)

how to solve this?

my test code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp> 

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;  


int main()
{
    string filepath( "H:\\DataSets\\xxx" );
    int a = fs::file_size(filepath.c_str());

}
```

Comment: Exactly which libs are you linking?

Comment: C:\local\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-1_55.lib

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment, you are only linking with `boost::filesystem`. `boost::filesystem` depends on `boost::system` so you must also link to `boost::system`

Comment: I put C:\local\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-vc90-mt-1_55.lib and Searching C:\local\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib\boost_system-vc90-1_55.lib to the Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependency, as in the log.